# How to use navigate method with a URL containing a port and a path

Tags: c#, .net

I want to access a web configuration page of a device via a WebView.

At first I tried this code :

```
private async void DoWebNavigate()
        {
            try
            {
                WebView.Navigate(new Uri("http://192.168.2.200:8080/webvisu.htm"));

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Error : " + e.Message);
                await dlg.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
```

Return no error, but only a white page open.

Then I tried :

```
UriBuilder myUrl = new UriBuilder("http", "192.168.2.200", 8080, "webvisu.htm");


    private async void DoWebNavigate()
    {
        try
        {
            WebView.Navigate(new Uri(myUrl.Uri));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Error : " + e.Message);
            await dlg.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

Got a compilation error Argument 1 : cannot convert from `System.Uri` to `String`

Answer (score 0):

That compilation error is easy to explain: `UriBuilder.Uri` is returning an instance of `Uri` class itself, you do not need to use a constructor again (like you did with `new Uri(myUrl.Uri)`. So, just try something like that:

```
WebView.Navigate(myUrl.Uri);
```

Comment: Thank you, very clear answer! I did the change to the code, and it removed the compilation error. But it still open a complete white page.

Comment: What is the page content intended? Maybe, it is about some JavaScript things that require Chrome or FireFox only?

Comment: Could be... if it so, is there a way to show it from my app ?